# Script for scheduling busy times, similar to a calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a "vehicle scheduler" for my workplace that will display the dates and times a truck will be unavailable. [Here's the link to the Google Sheets where the script runs. I have set up two example "busy times" to show what I am doing](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i1cE0-0xnaNo84TPByDoXGItiZYkd5XYBgDAzHlSke0/edit?usp=sharing)

One adjustment that was requested from me is to do 30 minute increments, but then the amount of columns gets absolutely bonkers.

I am open to any recommendations to improve this tool, even if it means something better (and free) already exists.

I appreciate your input!

See code below... (I am **RIDICULOUSLY** novice at coding, so be kind :)

```
function processForm(formObject){
  var day = formObject.dow;
  var vehicle = formObject.vehicle;
  var jobName = formObject.job;
  var driverName = formObject.driver;
  var duration = formObject.duration;
  var startTime = formObject.startTime;
  var ampm = formObject.ampm;
  var location = formObject.location;
  var returnArray = [day, vehicle, jobName, driverName, duration, startTime, ampm, location]
  var startTimeColumn = 0;
  var startDayColumn = 2;
  var sduration = startTime;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Week View");

  if (day=="Monday"){
    startDayColumn = 26;
    }
  else if (day=="Tuesday"){
    startDayColumn = 50;
  }
  else if (day=="Wednesday"){
    startDayColumn = 74;
  }
  else if (day=="Thursday"){
    startDayColumn = 98;
  }
  else if (day=="Friday"){
    startDayColumn = 122;
  }
  else if (day=="Saturday"){
    startDayColumn = 146;
  }

  if (ampm=="PM"){
    startDayColumn+=12;
  }

  if (startTime==12){
    startTime = 0;
  }


  startTimeColumn = parseInt(startTimeColumn) + parseInt(startDayColumn) + parseInt(startTime);

  var columnA = ss.getRange(1,1,ss.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  for (var rr=0;rr<ss.getLastRow();rr++){
    if (columnA[rr]==vehicle){
      break;
      }


    }
  rr +=1;
  for (var cc=0; cc<duration; cc++){
    var checkColumn = parseInt(cc) + parseInt(startTimeColumn);
    if (ss.getRange(rr, checkColumn).isBlank()){}
    else return "It looks like that time is booked :(";
  }
  var displayString = "Job: " + jobName + String.fromCharCode(10) + "Driver: " + driverName + String.fromCharCode(10) + sduration + ":00 " + ampm + String.fromCharCode(10) + location;
  var merging = ss.getRange(rr,startTimeColumn,1,duration).mergeAcross();
  var enterInfo = ss.getRange(rr, startTimeColumn).setValue(displayString);
  if (rr % 2 == 0){
  enterInfo.setBackgroundRGB(45, 114, 157);
  }
  else {enterInfo.setBackgroundRGB(26, 153, 136);}
  enterInfo.setFontColor('white')
  return "Success! Load has been booked to the scheduler.";

}
```

Comment: Why not using Google Calendar? I think it's best and easiest way for you...

Comment: Seems as though you are trying make Google Sheets jump through hoops. It is just as easy to keep your data in Google sheets and update information to Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making Sheets jump thru hoops and create a interface for inserting data and a Calendar to show it, why not use Forms and Calendar to do it all?

## What I have in mind

- Sheets as a long-time database for Truck Information and schedules
- Calendar as a way to visualize the availability of Trucks
- Forms as a interface for data-input

## Set-up

- A Spreadsheet file with a "List of Trucks" Sheet.
- A Form attached to it that allows users to insert information about the truck booking.

To make this work, I have inputted some data on out *List of Trucks*:

[image: List of Trucks]

Then I associated a form with that sheet and setup some basic questions:

[image: Forms Questions]

I also modified the forms settings to allow people to edit it on the future, this will allow us to add information to the calendar to tie an event with a response form the form.

[image: Modified Form Settings]

I added a script to the Forms that populates the first question with the data from our sheets:

```
function populateForm() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var TruckIdQ = form.getItems()[0];

  var truckList = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("YOUR SHEET URL").getSheetByName("List of Trucks").getDataRange().getValues().map(function (row) { return row[0]});
  truckList.shift(); //Remove header

  var choices = [];

  for (var i=0; i< truckList.length; i++) {
    choices.push(TruckIdQ.asListItem().createChoice(truckList[i]));
  }

  TruckIdQ.asListItem().setChoices(choices);
}
```

And set it to be run when the form is opened:

[image: Form OnOpen Trigger]

After that I went back to my sheets and modified the automatic Responses sheet to have a more understandable name: "Bookings".

Now we need to create a shared calendar to put all this information on it.

I created one named "Truck Booking Calendar" in the following way:

[image: Created Calendar]
[image: Sharing Settings]
[image: Notification Settings]

I then created a new Script on the Forms responsible for populating the calendar with information.

```
function populateCalendar(e) {
  var bookingCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("CALENDAR ID");

  var questions = FormApp.getActiveForm().getItems();
  var response = e.response.getItemResponses();


  var eventDescription = "";
  var truckname;
  var fromDate, toDate;
  var fromTime, toTime;

  for (var i=0; i< questions.length; i++) {
    eventDescription = eventDescription + questions[i].getTitle() + " : " + response[i].getResponse() + "\n";
    switch (i) {
      case 0:
        //Truck Id
        truckname = response[i].getResponse();
        break;
      case 1:
        //From Date
        fromDate = response[i].getResponse();
        break;
      case 2:
        //To Date
        toDate = response[i].getResponse();
        break;
      case 3:
        //From Time
        fromTime = response[i].getResponse();
        break;
      case 4:
        //To Time
        toTime = response[i].getResponse();
        break;
    }
  }

  var startDateTime = new Date(fromDate + " " + fromTime);
  var endDateTime = new Date(toDate + " " + toTime);

  var newEvent = bookingCalendar.createEvent("Booking "+truckname, startDateTime, endDateTime, {description:eventDescription});
  newEvent.setTag("truck", truckname);
  newEvent.setTag("responseId", e.response.getEditResponseUrl());
  newEvent.setTag("responseUrl", e.response.getId());
}
```

And created a trigger for it like this:

[image: On Submit Trigger]

Now, when I submit this into the form:

[image: Form input]

I get this entry on my calendar:

[image: Calendar event created!]

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Hi @ZektorH first off, thanks so much for taking the time to go through this and explain the steps. I think this is much better than all the hoops I was jumping through before.

I'm having difficulty viewing the event on my calendar. I've followed exactly as you have instructed and have even kept the same code (although I plan to re-write once I get this working, so that I can truly understand the steps)

Do I need authorization from google API? That's the only thing I have found on Class Calendar that I think would affect the calendar... not sure if you would have any suggestions

Comment: Alex F, could you open your calendar and [export it](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37111)? You should have the events inside of that. If you do, but they don't show up or have any unexpected data, let me know.